# How to make a Text take up the entire width with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a Text element, and it has textAlign: 'center' on it. The problem is its width doesn't take up the entire space, so the text doesn't appear centered. See below:

Text doesn't take up the entire width:

[image]

Inside of a bigger container:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the styling of any parent containers? Thanks.

Comment: I did, the second screenshot shows the parent View is taking up the center 300 width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the parent has `flex` style and set the style `alignItems : 'center'`